# Libgdx and Box2d Rotate Texture along with CircleSgape

Tags: box2d, libgdx

I want to make a ball, so far I have rendered as simple texture on my circle and the ball rotates by the texture does not. Here is what I have so far:

```
    bodyDef = new BodyDef();  
    bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;  
    bodyDef.position.set(new Vector2(240,320));  
    body = world.createBody(bodyDef);  
    CircleShape dynamicCircle = new CircleShape();  
    dynamicCircle.setRadius(15f);  
    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();  
    fixtureDef.shape = dynamicCircle;  
    fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;  
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.5f;  
    fixtureDef.restitution = 0.8f;  
    body.createFixture(fixtureDef); 
    body.applyTorque(100000000);
```

And in render I have:

```
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(texture, body.getPosition().x,body.getPosition().y);
    batch.end();
    world.step(BOX_STEP, BOX_VELOCITY_ITERATIONS, BOX_POSITION_ITERATIONS);
```

Any ideas how I can make the texture rotate as well? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should probably accept the answer if the solution worked for you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 batch.draw(texture, body.getPosition().x, body.getPosition().y, width/2, height/2, width, height, /*scaleX*/1, /*scaleY*/1, /*rotation*/ body.getAngle() * MathUtils.radToDegree, srcX, srcY, srcWidth, srcHeight, /*flipX*/false, /*flipY*/false);
```

Comment: The problem is he couldnot get the texture to rotate but the ball rotates. So the above function sets the size, origin , position , scaling factor and rotation value of the texture.